# Can't smooth scroll while centering a div vertically

Tags: javascript, css, smooth-scrolling

I have a div that I have centered both vertically and horizontally:

```
#mydiv {
  width:960px;
  height:400px;
  position:fixed;
  margin-left:-480px;
  margin-top:-200px;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
}
```

When I am using the Smoothscroll.js library it won't work. If I remove the "position:fixed/position:absolute" it do, but then my div is no longer centered. Is it any whay I can achieve both smooth scroll and centering?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem by myself. I made a fake (invisible) div at the top of the screen that changes height after screen-size. Then I put my visible (#mydiv) under that without any css positioning.

```
#mydivfake {
  width:1000px;
  height: calc(50vh - 310px); /*310px is half of the height of my visible centered div*/
  margin-left:-500px;
  left:50%;
}
```